# display a specific column in sql to a textbox asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, textbox

What i want to do is to get a specific column in my database. Currently i have ID, Username, Lastname, Firstname, Email, CreditRequest and Contact. I want credit request column to be displayed in my asp textbox. Any tricks you can share?

i am thinking something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
{
    scn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CreditRequest FROM CreditRequests WHERE Username=@Username", scn);
```

Comment: You need only to execute that command, get back the result and update the text property of your textbox.

Comment: hi @Steve would you mind giving me a sample code for that? it will be greatly appreciated especially to a beginner like me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete your code with the appropriate call to the method that executes the command and get back the result. I suppose that only one record is returned by that query, so calling ExecuteScalar is very efficient.

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
{
    scn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CreditRequest FROM CreditRequests WHERE Username=@Username", scn);

    // Add the parameter required by the query....
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = variableWithYouUserNameValue;

    // Run the query and get the single row/column returned
    object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    // If it is not null (possible if the where fails) then put on textbox
    if(value != null)
        txtBoxCredit.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Of course I don't know the real name of your textbox, so I have choosen a fictional name, change it with the real name of your textbox. The same for the variable that contains the current username to search for.

Comment: Well, you are searching data for a user _WHERE Username=@Username_  So in your application, before reaching this point, you should have gathered the UserName value to pass as parameter to the query. This should be some kind of string variable that you have defined and read from some kind of input

Comment: yes i have typed in Session["New"], it worked now :)

Comment: may i ask you another question. is it possible to do the same thing but the button is on a different webpage (ADMIN)? and when i click on the button, it will be directed on the textbox that we just did (CLIENT).

Comment: Probably yes using some kind of Session variable and a redirect, But at this point I suggest to post a new question where more users will see your problem and not adding confusion to this straightforward question

Comment: alright thank you. will do. just one more thing, after i click on the button, it shows the value and thats what i wanted for now. but when i leave that page, the textbox value disappears. is there any way to save that value for good?

Comment: [ASP.NET ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3)